# python : list and dictionary, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python-2.7

**i want to calculte the specfic numbers of words from the given sentence...words are alredy save in my dictonary and sentence is will be input from user.....
Here is my code.**

```
from collections import Counter

Find_word= raw_input('Write Sentence:')

wordTosearch=['is', 'am']

sentence= Find_word.split()

cnt = Counter(sentence)




for k in sentence:

   if k in wordTosearch:
    print k, wordTosearch[k]

if cnt[wordTosearch]>1:

  print "aggresive"
else:

  print "Not agressive"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What you wrote simply doesn't make sense... also `cnt[wordTosearch]` is nonsensical too, since you'd index a mapping with a list... do you want to check if all values are `> 1`? Then you `if all(value > 1 for value in cnt.values())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

Find_word= raw_input('Write Sentence:')
sentence= Find_word.split()
cnt = Counter(sentence)

wordTosearch=['is', 'am']

for k in wordTosearch:
    print k, cnt[k]

if all( cnt[x] > 1 for x in wordTosearch ):
    print "aggresive"
else:
    print "Not agressive"
```

I dont know what the bottom part should do though.

Answer (score 0):

`wordTosearch` is a list of words.

The following is iterating through that list of words:

```
if k in wordTosearch:
    print k, wordTosearch[k]  # <----
```

where `k` is a word, and `wordTosearch[k]` is the attempt to access a list value by a string key which gives you *"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"*.
You can not access list values by string indices as *Python* lists are "numbered" sequences